# how to install a 'Like' button for individual products

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I would like to install the 'Like' button for individual products on a specific page. Is their way to do this?. I have only been able to install the 'LIke' button for the page itself. Sample I have 3 products on a page. I need 3 'Like' buttons on this page in order for a user to be specific on which products they like.

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before asking a question.
This question has been asked a lot and has already been answered. See [Facebook like button on posts not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301433/facebook-like-button-on-posts-not-working-properly/)

Answer (score 0):

Open Graph (Protocol) basically assumes that each object (=product) has their own URL & web-page. That way its easy, you just have to set the correct og:title, og:url, og:image etc. on each product-page.

```
http://yourdomain.com/product-A
http://yourdomain.com/product-B
http://yourdomain.com/product-C
```

On the product-overview-page http://yourdomain.com/products you'ld then just have 3 like-buttons:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://yourdomain.com/product-A"/>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://yourdomain.com/product-B"/>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://yourdomain.com/product-C"/>
```

Done!

If, for some reason, you don't have separate product-pages, you'll have to setup "dummy"-pages on separate URLs for the Facebook Crawler. You'ld then detect the crawler by user-agent and deliver it the correct set of OG-metatags (the pages don't have to contain more than the  with tags). Normal users should be redirected to the product-overview-page. Here's some PHP code that should do that:

```
<?php
if (!(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]),"facebookexternalhit") === false)) {
  // Its Facebook crawler, give him what he needs!
  echo '<html><head>';
  echo '<meta property="og:title" content="Product A">';
  echo '<meta property="og:url" content="http://yourdomain.com/product-A">';
  echo '</head></html>';
} else {
  // normal user, lets redirect
  header("Location: http://yourdomain.com/products");
}
?>
```